# How to get modification date of a template file with local timezone in python flask

Tags: python, flask, timezone, pytz

I have a problem in getting file modified date with local timezone.It always shows the datetime in server default timezone.I have to change it to indian time.(Asia/Kolkata).
I have pytz installed ,but i don't know how to use it to change the server timezone and get file modification time accordingly.Please suggest me.Here is my code :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import os.path, time
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
 
   f=os.path.abspath("templates/index.html")

 
 fts=time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(f))
dt= time.strftime('%d %b  %Y %l:%M %p',fts)
mdt=str(dt)
return render_template('index.html',mdate=mdt)
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import os.path, time
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<tz1>/<tz2>")
def home():
   f=os.path.abspath("templates/index.html")
   tz = timezone(tz1+'/'+tz2)
   dt= datetime.now(tz)
   mdt=str(dt)
   return render_template('index.html',mdate=mdt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Now you can access it here:

127.0.0.1:5000/Asia/Kolkata

Comment: I need the modification date of the index.html file, which is on the Asia /Kolkata timezone.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_lastmodified.asp ?

Comment: Yes..last modified date of index.html template file in Asia/Kolkata timezone

Comment: AAAAh, will do it in a few minutes

Comment: Okay.. waiting.. brother

Comment: Sorry, but it is a complex question. Better get an experienced coder...